# cython - wrap a cpp class aggregating an other

Tags: python, c++, cython

I would like to create a wrapper for a cpp class with Cython. But this class aggregates an other one and I don't know if i need to also create a wrapper for this class as I don't want to call this second class from Python.

There are the cpp classes:

testclass.hpp

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H
#include "ocean.hpp"

class TestClass {
    private:
        Ocean _ocean;

    public:
        int x, y;
        TestClass();
        ~TestClass();
        int Multiply(int a, int b);
};
#endif
```

testclass.cpp

```
#include "testclass.hpp"
TestClass::TestClass()
{
    x = 5;
    y = 1;
    _ocean = Ocean();
}

TestClass::~TestClass()
{
    std::cout << "Calling destructor" << std::endl;
}

int TestClass::Multiply(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}
```

ocean.hpp

```
#ifndef OCEAN_H
#define OCEAN_H
class Ocean {
    public:
        double _depth;
        double _rho;

        Ocean();
        virtual ~Ocean();
        void setwaterdepth(double d);
};
#endif
```

I would like to wrap the test class only, This is what I have tried:

ocean.pxd

```
cdef extern from "ocean.hpp":
cdef cppclass Ocean:
    Ocean()
```

test.pyx

```
from ocean cimport Ocean

cdef extern from "testclass.hpp":
    cdef cppclass TestClass:
        TestClass()
        int x
        int y
        int Multiply(int a, int b)

cdef class pyTestClass:
    cdef TestClass* thisptr # hold a C++ instance

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new TestClass()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    def Multiply(self, a, b):
        return self.thisptr.Multiply(a, b)
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext = Extension("test",
                sources=["test.pyx", "testclass.cpp"],
                language="c++")

setup(name="test",
      ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

Q1) Is the right way of doing it ?
(When I compile this I get the following error and I don't understand the error. )

```
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c testclass.cpp -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\testclass.o
writing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\test.def
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\test.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\testclass.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\test.def -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild -LC:\Python27\PC\VS9.0 -lpython27 -lmsv
cr90 -o E:\00-Projets\InWave\Couplage\PYW\C++\test3\test.pyd
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\testclass.o:testclass.cpp:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `Ocean::~Ocean()'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\testclass.o:testclass.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `Ocean::~Ocean()'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\testclass.o:testclass.cpp:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `Ocean::Ocean()'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\testclass.o:testclass.cpp:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `Ocean::Ocean()'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\testclass.o:testclass.cpp:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to `Ocean::~Ocean()'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\testclass.o:testclass.cpp:(.text+0x196): undefined reference to `Ocean::~Ocean()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Sorry ! I have edited the error log because it was the wrong one. The : has been added and I still get an error in the generated test.cpp file.

Comment: It does not change the error.

Comment: I try it, I have only a error from setup. I notice that you forget to include `iostream` in `testclass.cpp` and you don't provide implementation of `Ocean`. Why do you `from ocean cimport Ocean`? Note that I don't know anything about cython.

Comment: Yes I didn't include iostream in the post but it is on my code. I was thinking that the implementation of `Ocean` was not important. I try to cimport Ocean because TestClass has an attribute Ocean.

Comment: Without the import the following error occurs: `In file included from test.cpp:259:0:
testclass.hpp:7:9: error: 'Ocean' does not name a type
         Ocean _ocean:`

Comment: Include guards in your headers? (ocean.hpp is included twice)

Comment: It's effectively better with the right include guards(I edited the code above) but now in the linking step of compilation no reference to Ocean constructor and destructor are found. Do I need to wrap this class too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally manage to make it work.

There is no need to wrap the Ocean class and consequently to create a `.pxd` file for it.
But in `setup.py` it is important to include all `.cpp` dependancies.

As said in previous comments it is also important to add include guard in headers file.

So here is a working code (compiled with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`)

ocean.hpp

```
#ifndef OCEAN_H
#define OCEAN_H

class Ocean {
    public:
        double _depth;
        double _rho;

        Ocean();
        virtual ~Ocean();
        void setwaterdepth(double d);
};

#endif
```

testclass.hpp

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_H
#define TESTCLASS_H
#include "ocean.hpp"

class TestClass {
    private:
        Ocean _ocean;

    public:
        int x, y;
        TestClass();
        virtual ~TestClass();
        int Multiply(int a, int b);
        void _set_x(int x);
};

#endif
```

testclass.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testclass.hpp"
#include "ocean.hpp"

TestClass::TestClass()
{
    x = 5;
    y = 1;
    _ocean = Ocean();
    std::cout << "Calling constructor" << std::endl;
}

TestClass::~TestClass()
{
    std::cout << "Calling destructor" << std::endl;
}

int TestClass::Multiply(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}

void TestClass::_set_x(int new_x)
{
    x = new_x;
}
```

test.pyx

```
cdef extern from "testclass.hpp":
    cdef cppclass TestClass:
        TestClass()
        int x
        int y
        int Multiply(int a, int b)

cdef class pyTestClass:
    cdef TestClass* thisptr # hold a C++ instance

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new TestClass()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    def Multiply(self, a, b):
        return self.thisptr.Multiply(a, b)

    property y:

        # Here we use a property to expose the public member
        # y of TestClass to Python

        def __get__(pyTestClass self):
            return self.thisptr.y

        def __set__(pyTestClass self, value):
            self.thisptr.y = <int> value
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext = Extension("test",
            sources=["test.pyx", "testclass.cpp", "ocean.cpp"],
            language="c++")

setup(name="test", ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

test of the wrapping

```
import test as wrapper

T = wrapper.pyTestClass()
print T.Multiply(3, 5)
print T.y
T.y = 3
print T.y
```

outputs

```
Calling ocean constructor
Calling ocean constructor
Calling ocean destructor
Calling constructor
15
1
3
Calling destructor
Calling ocean destructor
```